# Unable to push to GitHub due to 'Permission denied (publickey)' with configured ssh-keys

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I already configured ssh keys on my desktop some times but there, its different but I dont know why.
In my computer I have 3 git accounts, one for me (github), one for my work(github) and finally, one for my school(gitlab). I have already configured a key for my school and all is ok, I can use it. But its different for my personnal acounts or my work..

I have generated my ssh key with :

> ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "myemailaddress"

I took the content of the public key and I set it on github but when I tried to push my work I had the following error message :

`git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

So I check it in SOF and the documentation of github and then I used this command to check the status :

> ssh -vT git@github.com

(I dont remember the exact message because I closed it but the message said something like it cant etablish a connection.)

So then I saw something probably usefull for windows and I used these commands to activate ssh-agent

> Get-Service | ?{$_.Name -like '*ssh-agent*'} | select -Property Name, StartType, Status

> Set-Service -Name ssh-agent -StartupType Manual

> Start-Service ssh-agent

And finally, I could use commands with ssh-agent so I add my ssh key with

> ssh-add mySshPrivateKey

And now When I use `ssh-add -l` I have my ssh key with the correct key in github but I cant push my work again.
I really dont know why I cant now because I think that my key is correctly associated on my github account but it's not.

I really need help, I really dont know what is the problem...
Thank you.

[ssh -Tv git@github.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa1Ao.png)

Comment: This should help you [Multiple SSH Keys settings for different github account](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996)

Comment: It sounds like there's a network issue connecting to GitHub, but without the text of the error message you received I can't be certain. Could you please run `ssh -Tv git@github.com` again, and this time post what it returns?

Comment: Yes sure I will post it now